CANoe Identifies Constructed Ethernet Frame as Unknown PDU Despite Correct Configuration
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to send an automotive Ethernet frame using the packet builder feature in CANoe. Despite configuring the frame with the necessary IP, UDP, and IPv4 parameters, CANoe consistently marks the constructed frame as an "Unknown PDU," even when the message ID appears to be correct.
Frame Construction Details:
Ethernet:
MAC Destination: [xx] ,MAC Source: [xx],VLAN: x ,VLAN ID: [xxx],Type: IPv4
IPv4: Version: [x], Header Length: [x],Checksum: [0xxxx],Source IP: [xxxxxxxxx],Destination IP: [xxxxxxxx]
UDP:Source Port: [xxxxxx],Destination Port: [xxxxxxxx],Payload: [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
Issue Encountered:
Despite meticulously configuring the Ethernet frame with accurate parameters and ensuring that the message ID is correct, CANoe consistently identifies the frame as an "Unknown PDU." This issue persists even after thorough verification of the frame's construction and the parameters provided.
Expected Outcome:
I expect CANoe to correctly recognize the constructed automotive Ethernet frame and process it according to the specified parameters. However, the persistent labeling of the frame as an "Unknown PDU" indicates a discrepancy or oversight in the frame construction process or in CANoe's interpretation of the provided parameters.
Request for Assistance:
Seeking guidance on troubleshooting steps or potential solutions to resolve the issue of CANoe misidentifying the constructed Ethernet frame as an "Unknown PDU." Any insights or recommendations from individuals experienced with CANoe or automotive Ethernet communication protocols would be greatly appreciated.
Steps Taken to Resolve:
Double-checked the configuration of MAC addresses, VLAN ID, IP addresses, and ports to ensure accuracy.
Verified the correctness of the message ID associated with the frame.
Reviewed CANoe documentation and forums for similar issues and potential solutions.
Experimented with variations in frame construction parameters to identify potential sources of the problem.

The PDU is described in the attached arxml-file?

What is the definition of the PDU in the ARXML? a) is it put into a ContainerIPdu, which requires a (long/short)header, b) is it a SOME/IP PDU, which requires a headerId, if more than 1 PDU is handled over the same port? The HeaderId usually if FFFF8100 for SD, and overwise ServiceID+Event/MethodID.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
